# Applied load on a Stapler

Tags: experimental-physics, solid-mechanics

I'm trying to do a finite element analysis on a stapler I created in Solidworks. In order to do this I have needed a set load being applied to the top of the stapler.

Any ideas on how I would go about doing this?

Already tried applying my hand to a scale and then doing a simple $F=ma$ calculation but not sure if this is too simple.

Comment: It is not clear what your difficulty is, nor how the experiment relates to finite element analysis. A set load could be a set weight, such as a 1kg bag of sugar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you press the scale with your finger, the value in the display is probably in units of mass. If it is in kg, multiplying by 9,8 results in a force in N.

You can use that point force in the model, or estimate the contact area of the finger and use a distributed load.